# background image change in css onmousehover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a menu like mega menu but nothing is working for me, I am pasting my code for simple most results.

I have two divs, one for image and one for menu. on hovering link image in other div should change. CSS or JS no issue for me.

HTML=====

```
<div>

    <div id="img_div"></div>
    <div id="links_div">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Show image 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Show image 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Show image 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Show image 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Show image 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS======

```
<style>
 #img_div{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: url("images/default.jpg");
    float: left;
}
 #links_div{
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul li{
    display: block;
}
ul li a{
}
</style>
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Are you trying to do some kind of thumbnail gallery rather than a menu? It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a code sample using click let me know if this is what you are looking for. My guess is that you can replace "click" with "hover" if I have understood your problem correctly.

**Update:** Capture mouse events instead of click

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#links_div a").on("mouseenter", function() {    
    $("#img_div").addClass($(this).attr('data-class'));
  });
  
  $("#links_div a").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $("#img_div").removeClass($(this).attr('data-class'));
  });
});
```

```css
#img_div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
}
#img_div.a {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/200x200?text=a");
}
#img_div.b {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/200x200?text=b");
}
#img_div.c {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/200x200?text=c");
}
#img_div.d {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/200x200?text=d");
}
#img_div.e {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/200x200?text=e");
}
#links_div {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
}
ul li a {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="img_div"></div>
  <div id="links_div">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="a">Show image 1</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="b">Show image 2</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="c">Show image 3</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="d">Show image 4</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="e">Show image 5</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jquery has rich [mouse events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) all you need to is capture appropriate event and remove the class. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Wasn't *my* question...:)

Answer (score 0):

Have a CSS rule that only affects the div with class `altImage`:

```
#img_div.altImage {
    background: url("images/alt.jpg");
}
```

Using javascript, add a class to the div on hover:

```
var links = document.getElementById("links_div");

links.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
    document.getElementById("img_div").classList.add("altImage");
});

links.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
    document.getElementById("img_div").classList.remove("altImage");
});
```

That should work